# Symfony 2 project in nested directory

Tags: php, symfony

I need to deploy a Symfony 2 project in nested directory on production server. Effectively, this would mean that all URLs are prefixed with /subdirectory/ path, i.e.

```
http://host.com/subdirectory/project/web/app.php/survey
```

I don't need URL rewriting and are am not going to set it up. The app should work when accessed via above URL only.

The problem I have is that all links generated by `path` and `asset` Twig functions are relative to server root (*/*), and not subdirectory the project is in (*/subdirectory/*). Is there any config parameter in Symfony 2 to override relative paths globally?

I tried to work around that problem by adding HTML  tag, but it doesn't work for  links.

**Update:** I owe you further details. I'm running IIS with its version of mod_rewrite, so part of your suggestions may still be valid.

**Update:** Ideally I would like to see a solution that sets root dir on AppKernel object - method `AppKernel::setRootDir()` had it existed to complement existing `AppKernel::getRootDir()`.

Comment: "I don't need URL rewriting and are am not going to set it up", trust me you do want to set it up.

Comment: Can you expand on this a little bit? I blocked access to anything else than app.php and assets.

Comment: Set your doc root proper, pointing to the web dir.

Comment: @Pazi - I'm not in control of that. It HAS TO run from where it is now.

Comment: Can you dump the `$_SERVER` variable on the prod server? Simply in a testscript next to the `app.php`.

Answer (score 3):

Strange... with default config, path/asset should handle subdirectories. Have you tried it with symfony distribution out-of-the-box? On localhost im mostly using it this way.
Would you mind posting your config file?

Anyway...
For assets paths you could try to configure:

```
#config.yml
templating:
  assets_base_urls: { http: "http://yoursite.com/dir1", ssl: "https://yoursite.com/dir1" }
```

(http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/framework.html#assets-base-urls)

For router you should read: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/console/sending_emails.html#configuring-the-request-context-globally
It could give you some ideas about changing router context like:

```
# app/config/parameters.yml
parameters:
  router.request_context.host: example.org
  router.request_context.scheme: http
  router.request_context.base_url: my/path
```

Anyway - context is automaticlly set based on request information. Try to debug:

```
$context = $this->getContainer()->get('router')->getContext();
// you should be mainly interested in:
$context->getBaseUrl();
```

It is possible to easily create listener class which will manually set your base url if anyhow it is wrong:

```
class RouterContextListener {

    protected $router;

    public function __construct(RouterInterface $router)
    {
        $this->router = $router;
    }

    public function onKernelRequest(Event $event)
    {
        $this->router->setBaseUrl('somedir');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for [RewriteBase](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase) rule, add it to your in your `.htaccess`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /subdirectory/project/web
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L] 
</IfModule>
```

---

Also take a look onto symfony-standard 2.3 [.htaccess](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/blob/2.3/web/.htaccess) file, mb it can help

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
    RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]

    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
    RewriteRule ^app\.php(/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$2 [R=301,L]

    # If the requested filename exists, simply serve it.
    # We only want to let Apache serve files and not directories.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule .? - [L]

    # Rewrite all other queries to the front controller.
    RewriteRule .? %{ENV:BASE}/app.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at app/config/routing.yml where you import routing from your bundles. Records in that file would look similar to this:

```
somename:
    resource: "@YourBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /
```

You can add your subdirectory in prefix,  like `prefix:   /subdirectory`
Then all generated URLs will include `subdirectory`.

Comment: I'm afraid that's not what I need. Your proposal would make look example link like http://host.com/project/web/app.php/subdirectory/foo/bar whereas what I need is http://host.com/subdirectory/project/web/app.php/foo/bar

Answer (score 0):

To enable it the rewrite module, run "apache2 enable module rewrite":

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

You need to restart the webserver to apply the changes:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

VirtualHost should be like this
    
    ServerName localhost.myproject.dev
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/project_path
<Directory /var/www/project_path>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /app.php [QSA,L]
    </IfModule>
</Directory>
```

this option is redirect your index.php, index.html or whatever:

```
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
```

it will rewrite your htacces!

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /app.php [QSA,L]
    </IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution to this on a local environment was adding the following code in `app/config/config.yml`

```
framework:
    assets:
        base_urls:
            - 'http://localhost/symfony_dir/'
```

No rewrite needed!