# Symfony 4 deploy on IIS in a nested directory

Tags: symfony, iis, deployment, directory, web-config

I want to deploy a new Symfony 4 project (the symfony-demo) from local to a IIS web server. The project should stay in its own sub directory. The IIS webroot is two levels higher. When I go to public/index.php of my project (which is releative to the webroot in /sf/symfony-demo/), the templates are not shown correctly, since the server does not find the correct JavaScript directory in build/js/...), see screenshot

[image: symfony 4 demo, build/js not found]

I call `http://192.168.1.203/sf/symfony-demo/public/index.php`, but fails to  load from `http://192.168.1.203/build/manifest.js`.
On the server, I can not set the webroot or create virtual directores. Also, I have no command line. I need to do it via configuration in symfony or a correct write/rewrite rule in web.config file.

How can I set the sf- project root directory relative to the IIS webroot, in my case to `/sf/symfony-demo/public` ?

Can somebody provide a rewrite rule in `web.config` in  /sf/symfony-demo/ or in /sf/symfony-demo/public? Or do I need to set the directory somewhere (prefix? asset?) in my project configuration files (e.g. \sf\symfony-demo\config\packages\framework.yml)?

**Edit**

I got it working somehow, there is a similar discussion and a solution for a symfony 2 project:

[Symfony 2 project in nested directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18715703/symfony-2-project-in-nested-directory)
 by adding in `symfony-demo\config\packages\framework.yaml` a line at `assets` :

```
base_urls:
    - 'http://192.168.1.203/sf/symfony-demo/public/'
```

But somehow this looks strange for me to set the path this way. Setting here

```
base_path: '/sf/symfony-demo/public/'
```

does not work. I would expect to set the (relative) path explicitly somewhere, not a url.  But where?

Also, setting `extra.symfony-public-dir` in `composer.json` like  in 
http://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration/override_dir_structure.html

does not work.

Regarding the rewrite rules:
Yes I read the doc, but I found nothing for web.config on iis for symfony on

https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/web_server_configuration.html.

But I found a iis web.config for silex
[https://silex.symfony.com/doc/2.0/web_servers.html .

It looks like the web.config is not the real problem here.
Thank you for taking the time to read this. d.

Comment: If this question would indeed be best served with an web server rewrite rule, readers would be most grateful if you would try to write that yourself first. We are already inundated with requests for free labour for rewrite rules, regular expressions and SQL queries in particular. In fact, we try to resist requests for free work in general, but these are the worst ones. If you can do that, it will ensure you're not merely trying to get someone to do your work for you, and readers will thus be more willing to help.

Comment: That said, I wonder if your public web folder is merely set wrongly. The folder `public` should be your docroot, so if you have to put `public/` in your URL, then your docroot needs resetting.

Comment: Have you considered looking at the web server configuration sections in the docs?